# SeriLog fileSizeLimitBytes attributes asp.net Core

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, serilog, rollingfilesink

We are using asp.net Core 1.1 and are using SeriLog to create log file within the application.

Now to control size of log file, I added attribute fileSizeLimitBytes

```
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "RollingFile",
      "Args": {
        "pathFormat": "Logs/LogFileConf-{Date}-test.Log",
        "fileSizeLimitBytes": 500000
      }
    }
  ],
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
  "Properties": {
    "Application": "Sample",
    "Environment": "Test"
  }
},
```

In this case, writing to log file stopped and when I removed above attributes, writing to log file again started working

So I have added as follows
    "pathFormat": "Logs/LogFileConf-{Date}-test.Log",
    "fileSizeLimitBytes": 500000

I am not sure what I am missing here.

```
Project.json contains following reference.
"Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.2.0",
"Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile": "3.0.1",
"Serilog.Settings.Configuration": "2.1.0"
```

Can anybody help here to solve this issue?

Comment: It would help if you can include your configuration directly in the question - cheers!

Comment: I have added configuration details

Answer (score 0):

Is your log file already > 500,000 bytes? That's not a high limit, so chances are the logging stops because the file is already above it.

See *Serilog.Sinks.File* 4.0+ if you are looking for roll-on-file-size.

Comment: We added Seilog.Sinks.File in appsettings.json file, and included rolling file attribute as mentioned in question, but now it does not write anything in log file, can you please share example for the same? It seems i am missing something here